# How to detect ambient noise in android using Recorder

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I'm trying to detect when there is too much auditory noise. I'm new to Android, and I don't know how to do detect external noise levels.

An attempt I tried was to display the value of noise using the `recorder` methods: `getAudioSource` and `getMaxAmplitude` methods.

```
 public void startRecording() throws IOException {

                numeSunet=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".3gp";

                recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".3gp");
   recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
        int x = recorder.getMaxAmplitude();

            snt.setText(""+x);

        }public void stopRecording() {
        recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();

        }
```

In my case, y is always 0, and x is always 8. 
I would appreciate if somebody knows how to detect audio noise levels in android.

Answer (score 1):

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181449/android-detect-sound-level):

1. Use mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
2. For the analysis of sound without saving all you need is use mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");

Here´s an example, I hope this helps

```
public class SoundMeter {

    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

    public void start() {
            if (mRecorder == null) {
                    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null"); 
                    mRecorder.prepare();
                    mRecorder.start();
            }
    }

    public void stop() {
            if (mRecorder != null) {
                    mRecorder.stop();       
                    mRecorder.release();
                    mRecorder = null;
            }
    }

    public double getAmplitude() {
            if (mRecorder != null)
                    return  mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
            else
                    return 0;

    }
}
```

EDIT:

Reading into the [API for MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#getMaxAmplitude%28%29) shows this...

> public int getMaxAmplitude ()

Added in API level 1

> Returns the maximum absolute amplitude that was sampled since the last
>   call to this method. Call this only after the setAudioSource().
>
> Returns the maximum absolute amplitude measured since the last call,
>   or 0 when called for the first time Throws IllegalStateException  if it
>   is called before the audio source has been set.

Comment: mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude() is always 0. What value should have if there is detected noise?

Comment: So, I don't use the right method to find if there is noise. How can I solve my problem?