# Android if statement in runnable not always firing

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write a simple little thing that stops an audio file from being played when the user "interrupts" it by talking to the phone.  I'm using the [`SoundMeter` class that this person wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14181707/821488) to get the maxAmplitude of the microphone.  I've set a threshold to `800` and want to test the return of the microphone amplitude against it constantly (every 50ms).

For some reason, it's hit or miss when I get the "interrupt" to show up and when the audio stops.  I'd like for the interrupt to be showing the entire time the amplitude is above 800.

```
    handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mic_amplitude.setText(""+mSoundMeter.getAmplitude());
            if(mSoundMeter.getAmplitude() > threshold) {
                Log.d("INTERRUPT", "INTERRUPT");
                interrupt.setText("Interrupt");
                mBackgroundAudio.pause(mp);
                audioButton.setText("Resume Audio");
            } else {
                interrupt.setText("");
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 50);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 50);
```

While viewing this, I'm able to see the amplitude at a steady 40-50 while there is no background noise and peaks of 1200-1500 when talking quietly. I'd like the interrupt to show anytime above 800, but it's currently only showing up intermittently.

Comment: I think 50 is too small but I don't know

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.  I tested what my amplitude was by logging the amp along with the interrupt and I saw I was getting 0.  I realized I had been testing on a new amplitude (other than the amp I was showing), so I assigned the amplitude to a variable and used the variable everywhere else.

here's my outcome:

```
    handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mAmplitude = mSoundMeter.getAmplitude();
            mic_amplitude.setText(""+mAmplitude);
            if(mAmplitude > threshold) {
                Log.d("INTERRUPT", "INTERRUPT " + mAmplitude);
                interrupt.setText("Interrupt");
                mBackgroundAudio.pause(mp);
                audioButton.setText("Resume Audio");
            } else {
                interrupt.setText("");
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 100);
```