# Android noise level detection and decibel calculation

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, android-audiorecord, decibel, android-sound

I have tried many examples of noise level detection from that some following examples I tried and debug:

- [Detect noise or blow sound](http://androidexample.com/Detect_Noise_Or_Blow_Sound_-_Set_Sound_Frequency_Thersold/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=108)
- [Android detect sound level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181449/android-detect-sound-level)
- [Google SplMeter sample code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/splmeter/downloads)

But I am get little bit confused on the following points:

- Difference between recording audio using Android MediaRecorder and AudioRecorder class (best settings to require good quality audio for both classes).
- How to calculate sound level into decibel using amplitude? (Please correct me if I am asking about wrong calculation or parameters)

Please share your ideas, documentation (that helps me to understand this concept), examples, tutorials, etc.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate decibels you need a background reading.  Decibels is the ratio of signal:noise, so you need to know what the background noise is.  Once you have that, the formula is db= 10*log(signal/noise)

Comment: But In which form I will get signal through android device (Is it in amplitude form or frequency?) and What is the value for noise?(Is it equals to 2700 or different?)

Comment: Amplitude.  Frequency wouldn't make sense here-  frequency is pitch, not loudness.  Noise wouldn't be a constant number, it would be the value on the device when there is no sound-  you calibrate it in a quiet environment.